# Can I add an output to a Terraform module that already exists in state?

Tags: terraform

I am working on importing some existing infrastructure into Terraform (Github repos and teams to be exact).

My Terraform resources are based on reusable modules.

For instance, I have a `repo` module, into which vars can be passed to create a new Github repository.

I have different state files for my repos and teams. The `repo` module calls out to the remote state of the teams resources, in order to obtain the team_id of the team that owns that module.

This requires my `team` module to create an output for each `team_id`.

For new repos and teams this works well.

However, my legacy team resources were not created with Terraform. They were imported, so the outputs were never created.

I can't figure out how to add the necessary output to each of my `team` modules. I have tried manually updating the terraform.tfstate file:

```
           "outputs": {
                "team_id": {
                    "sensitive": false,
                    "type": "string",
                    "value": "2814777"
                }
            },
```

But when I run the command:

```
terraform output module.my_team.github_team.team
```

The response says there are no outputs defined.

Is there a recommended way to add output values to modules if the resources that comprise those modules were imported rather than created with Terraform?

Answer (score 0):

So I resolved this myself. You can actually manually update a state file to add outputs to a module. Key points are:

When using `terraform_remote_state`, module outputs are only available if they exist in the root module. You can't remotely reference an output in a module nested in the root module.

Referencing outputs as vars isn't hugely intuitive. I had originally tried this:

`${data.terraform_remote_state.my_teams.outputs.team_a_id.value}`

The correct interpolation is:

`${data.terraform_remote_state.my_teams.team_a_id}`